# Why does IE9 go to about:blank before navigating to external link?

Tags: redirect, internet-explorer-9, bho

Environment:

IE9 with Group Policy applied and an automatic proxy script, which defines a set of internal (using DIRECT) and external sites are redirected to a proxy.

Desired behaviour:

Starting from an internal web site page, clicking on an external link makes IE navigate to the external page directly.

Problem:

If IE is not run as administrator, IE redirects first to about:blank for about a half a second, and then to the external page.
This is a problem when we try to prevent navigation to certain URLs by cancelling the BeforeNavigate2 event in a Browser Helper Object.
The problem is that when we try to prevent the navigation, the browser shows the about:blank page instead of staying on the original page.